# How to pull only rows that are filled in from a column to another Google sheet

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm looking to find a way to pull data from one column that has rows with data in them and apply that data to another Google sheet, and leaving out the empty rows in that column.

An example.

Let's pretend that people are filling out information about themselves.  They are asked their general information ie. age, sex, height, weight, marriage status. So column a-> age, b -> sex, c-> height, d-> weight, and e-> marriage status.

I would like to pull all the information (all rows from the columns) from those that answered yes in column e (marriage status) to another Google sheet. And ignore those who answered no or left it blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `QUERY` formula:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:E, "where E = 'yes'", 0)
```

or use `FILTER` formula:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:E, Sheet1E:E="yes")
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!